# How to detect double click while holding ctrl or shift to start a C# console program?

Tags: c#, process, mouse, startup, double-click

I'm writing a C# console program on Windows. Normally the program could be started by double clicking the icon in the File explorer, or typing its name in a command line. I hope to do some special task when the user double clicks the icon in the File explorer while holding down the ctrl or shift key. Is this possible? I know some program has this feature but I don't know how this is implemented or whether they are using C#.

Comment: What application has this feature?

Comment: If I remember correctly, in older versions of Tableau you can do such things. I'm sure there are other programs support this feature, I just can't remember their names.

Comment: Well your only option is to check if the key is down when you start. However this seems flakey, but i guess its doable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how To check if CTRL key is pressed in console application c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490168/how-to-check-if-ctrl-key-is-pressed-in-console-application-c-sharp)